# No Entity Framework provider found for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' ADO.NET provider

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to use Entity Framework with MySQL and I get the above error. I have the latest MySQL connector installed.

The full error reads:

```
No Entity Framework provider found for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' ADO.NET provider. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.
```

However, I can't find anything that suggests just how you register it in the 'entityFramework' section.

Some other posts ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355659/entityframework-6-alpha-2-mysql-connector-net-6-6-4)) suggest adding the provider to the `system.Data` `DbProviderFactories` section like this:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add 
    name="MySQL Data Provider"
    invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
    type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, 
    Version=6.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

But that doesn't work because it claims that the `invariant` name is duplicated. And, if I actually iterate through the `System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories` I can see the last one is the MySQL provider:

```
MySQL Data Provider
.Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL
MySql.Data.MySqlClient
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d
```

So the provider is there, but EF refuses to use it. Any ideas?

My full config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>

   <system.data>
   <!--<DbProviderFactories>
   <add 
    name="MySQL Data Provider"
    invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
    type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, 
    Version=6.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
   </DbProviderFactories>-->
</system.data>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myContext" connectionString="server=****;User Id=****;password=****;Persist Security Info=True;database=myDb"
  providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>

</entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I noticed that I had EF 6 installed. I removed it and tried EF 5 instead (which NuGet says is the latest stable version) and it started working.

Still, a more useful error message would have been nice!

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar and can't get the app.config right...  using .Net 4.5 and EF 5..   In your `<entityFramework>` section you still have the `<defaultConnectionFactory>` pointing to the default `LocalDbConnectionFactory`.  Where do you make it point to the `MySql` db?

Comment: Im not really sure how uninstalling EF6 and using something else can be marked as the correct answer to this problem.

Comment: @spryce: It's my question and my answer. It got it working. At the time EF 5 was the stable version but somehow I'd ended up with EF 6.

Answer (score 34):

in EF5 or less, all ok.
in EF6, you need to use mysql connector 6.8.x, and add DbConfigurationTypeAttribute to you DbContext:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class DemoContext : DbContext{}
```

which MySqlEFConfiguration is in MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll in 6.8.x. Have a try!

Comment: It works, but sucks as a solution because then code will depend on MySQL instead of just configuration...

Comment: Adding the attribute definitely solved my problem, but it is a pain having the MySQL dependency in code. Better approach would be to add this configuration as follows: <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">

Comment: I had the correct config but started seeing this error. I began changing my configuration according to the variations, but nothing worked. Then I closed VS.NET and reopened the solution and it all worked again.

Comment: Thanks buddy you save my day.

Answer (score 30):

You need to create this section in config (EF 5):

```
<entityFramework>
  <!-- ... -->
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
              type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

**Update:** Use this definition for EF 6:

```
<entityFramework>
  <!-- ... -->
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
              type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Thanks to **elcool**.

Comment: EF6 is now supported. I'm using connector 6.9.6, and in your code replace MySql.Data.Entity with MySql.Data.Entity.EF6  . And add the reference.

Comment: <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
              type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" /> Adding this is what did the trick for me. Thanks

Comment: Great ! Thanks . Save my time to configure the error.

Answer (score 9):

I just had the same situation when trying to configure Visual Studio Professional 2017 environment with MySQL, ADO.NET (Database First) and EF6.

After going through hell with every connector/NET available, I got it to work with Connector/NET v6.9.10 and following the steps below.

1. Uninstall/remove "Connector/NET" and "MySQL for Visual Studio" if installed.
2. Install "MySQL for Visual Studio" v2.0.5 CTP ([MySQL for Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=470092)).
   Note: Install MySQL for Visual Studio before Connector/NET.
3. Install "Connector/NET" v6.9.10 ([Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=474110)). 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOT1I.jpg Note: I tried using Connector/NET v6.8, v6.10 and v8 first, but none of them worked [Here you can find all Connector Versions and Compatibilities with Visual Studio IDEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html), but so far this list is inaccurate.
4. Download and Install "EntityFramework" v6.2.0 through NuGet.
5. Add references to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9.10\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll` 
   and
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9.10\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll`.
6. Add MySQL EF6 provider info inside App.config under entity framework providers as follow:

```html
<entityFramework>
       <providers>
         <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
              type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
       </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

7. Rebuild project.

And that was it. VS2017 was ready to go for me. Hope this works for everybody, as it did for me today.

**References**:

1. [Can't Create Entity Data Model - using MySql and EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38619052/3802757)
2. [No Entity Framework provider found for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' ADO.NET provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19898907)

Comment: comments are never supposed to be in answer section.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding a summary of versions (since I saw you are trying 6.2 which is way too old)

- For EF4, use Connector/NET 6.6.x (current GA is 6.6.6)
- For EF5, use Connector/NET 6.7.x (current GA  is 6.7.4) or Connector/NET 6.8.x (current GA is 6.8.3).
- For EF6, use Connector/NET 6.8.x (current GA is 6.8.3).

Comment: The question is almost a year old, so I don't know that it was too old at the time, but +1 for the helpful summary.

Comment: After switching my dev system, I spent two weeks to be able to run the app. Stumbled upon this answer finally. Finally app seems to work. +100. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

I've updated from EntityFramework 5.0 to 6.1 and MySQL connector 6.8.3 and only had to add the attribute to get things going again. Before adding the attribute everything would compile fine but crash at runtime.

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class DemoContext : DbContext{}
```

Comment: This was the answer for me. Hopefully this gets more upvotes and we'll have a more current accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I tried every different combination of config string and setup but I finally figured it out. My solution has the source code in one project and tests in another. I was using Entity Framework 6.1.1 and had installed MySql Connector 6.8.3 and MySql for Visual Studio 1.2.3.

The problem was that I had NuGet managing the packages, but only had them included in the main project. The solution was to

1. Right click on the Solution (top level in the solution explorer)
2. Manage Nuget packages for solution
3. Go to Installed tab
4. For all of the EntityFramework related packages (MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entities, MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity and MySql.ConnectorNET.Data), select them then select the "Manage" button.
5. Enable each package for all projects.

Comment: Thanks buddy you save my day.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, here's the official guide on using MySQL Connector/Net with EF 6 which includes all the necessary steps (assemblies, configs, ...etc.):
[Chapter 10 EF 6 Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

Answer (score 1):

Install latest version from nuget
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a missing reference. When you upgrade to EntityFramework 6, you need to add a reference to the assembly

> System.Data.Entity

I think it's because MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 inherits from a bunch of stuff in this assembly, that it did not for previous version of EF.

When your app.config is good and all your references seem fine, it's a solution worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

May just MySql provider is installed in machine-config (e. g. by .net connector installer? 
Also the default connection factory should be something like "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" i guess...