# EntityFramework not generating C# files properly (some enums are incomplete, so build fails)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, auto-generate

At work I just installed a brand new copy of my OS and a brand new copy of VS2015. When I clone my solution for the first time, I cannot build it anymore, even if I've generated the C# files like I always do, by opening the .edmx file first, and clicking on "save" icon.

When building it throws the error:

> CS0150: A constant value is expected

Because the enums that it has generated are incomplete! An example of one:

```
public enum DocumentType : int
{
    Identity = 1,
    ResidenceProof = 2,
    RegisterDoc = ,
}
```

I also had this compiler error at the time, but after fixing it my C# enums are still being generated wrongly:

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details

How the hell should I fix this problem?

Comment: What message is contained in the `InnerException`?

Comment: The following post might be helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142841/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-mysql-data-mysqlclient-ado-net-provider -- but I'm not certain.

Comment: @DavidTansey: not sure this is the same problem, I don't have exceptions but compiler errors

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you're saying.  I only asked because of the part of the message that says: _See the inner exception for details_   I would at least compare the relevant config sections that are referenced in that post to see if something helps to get a hint why EF is not behaving as you expect.

Comment: oh, but I go to see the build output and I don't see that error in there, so not sure where to look for the innerException :-/

Comment: I don't think you'll find it...The process of generating your model needs to access your MySql db, but the provider is messed up and it can't connect, the inner exception is buried in there where you probably cannot get at it.  But if you can get the config straightened out then you are probably good-to-go for generating your model.

Comment: I've fixed the latter issue by installing the .NET connector from MySQL website, but it still generates faulty enums :(

Comment: Simple question - did you double-check the row for Document type to make sure that the RegisterDoc entry does not possibly have a null where you expect a 3?  Seems highly unlikely but easy-to-check.  Your question is worded like there are other mis-generated enums.  Is that the case?  If so, does the problem have a pattern, for example: last element is always blank?

Comment: exactly, all enums have the last element always blank

Comment: Hi @knocte, did you ever resolve this issue? We're hitting the exact same problem. It's only on one of our machines, so it looks like it's something in the setup. Could it be culture related?

Comment: Haven't worked on this for a while so not sure my machine still generates the faulty enums... but other colleagues don't have this problem

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, VS2013 generated it correct earlier today but after installing VS2015 and generating the code, all my enums are missing the last element's value. This problem does not occur on my other development machines. I guess EF doesn't like a fresh VS2015? :(

Comment: my workaround is committing the generated files from the VS instances that generate them well :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. Turned out that texttransform.exe cannot understand different line endings well. My .tt file was saved with Unix EOL, and when I saved it with Windows EOL, it started to work correctly. Just that simple - open your .tt file in WordPad and save.

Comment: Excellent. FYI you can open the *.tt file(s) in VS and change the line endings to `CRLF` at the bottom-right of the document: https://i.imgur.com/EFc2Lz5.png

Comment: I can confirm this is still a problem in VS2019 and EF 6.2. This is the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer but i'll post my findings and the workaround i chose to use;

The T4 Code Generation template (The file attached to your .edmx file using the .tt file-extention) contains code to generate C# using the data available in your model, I suspect the code at line #204 (might be located on a different line number in your version) to contain a minor bug.

A screenshot from my active project and solution explorer:
[image: Code inside the .tt file]

This line causes the faulty enums:

```
    this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(this.GenerationEnvironment.Length - 3, 1);
```

This presumably removes generated code characters that were added by the enum generator in order to remove the last `,` from the enum, as it is unnecessary.

I tested the functionality of this by adding output in front of this line, i tried creating an enum that would output `MyEnumMemberName = TEST,` and found that the output contained `MyEnumMemberName = TES,`.

Using this I found that changing the line to:

```
    this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(this.GenerationEnvironment.Length - 2, 1);
```

solves my issue.

Can't currently check if this also works on the machines that were already generating correct code but I hope it helps some of you. Good luck.

Comment: sorry but where does this code come from? how do you locate it in VS? do you know if this is part of EF?

Comment: I use a model-first approach, in an empty project add a Entity Data Model (.edmx), open the model (Named Model1.edmx) and right click > Add Code Generation Item. This will add a Model1.tt item in your solution explorer tree beneath your Model1.edmx, the code i'm speaking of is inside this Model1.tt file.

Comment: I'm not sure which VS plugin injects the code into this Model1.tt file to begin with, it's probably EF. I'm still hoping to find an answer along the lines of 'Update your XX to version XX'

Comment: EF is opensource so we should be able to find the code that does this