# No Entity Framework provider found for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' ADO.NET provider MySQL .Net Connector

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, ado.net, entity-framework-6

This is the same question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142841/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-mysql-data-mysqlclient-ado-net-provider)

However, I've done all the solutions there to no avail.  Below is my App.config file

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
       <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
       type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, 
       EntityFramework.SqlServer" /></provider>

       <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
       type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, 
       MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.12.0, Culture=neutral"></provider>
</providers>
```

I've also edited the partial class generated by using EF database first approach

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public partial class DB_IATrans : DbContext
{
```

My .Net Connector is 6.9.12  Please let me know if there is further information I should post